# PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null) when using Flutter to build an appbundle

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, android-app-bundle, google-signin

I'm building a Flutter app with [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) and [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in).

Everything was working well for a while and all of my existing users on the released product have not experienced any problems, but a while back I started getting reports that new users couldn't log in.  I didn't think much of it until the reports started to accumulate.  I found that they were getting the error posted in the title.  I spent a ton of time investigating...

I've gone through all of the other StackOverflow entries for this issue:

1. [Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56122520/unhandled-exception-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-co)
2. [PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776534/platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception)
3. [Exception has occurred. PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440770/exception-has-occurred-platformexception-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com)
4. [Flutter: Firebase: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57978559/flutter-firebase-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-comm)
5. [Flutter: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043670/flutter-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-api)
6. [Flutter and google_sign_in plugin: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google)
7. [com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001068/com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10)
8. [com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51232938/com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10)
9. [How to correct " com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262477/how-to-correct-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10)
10. [Firebase Google Signin error: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861698/firebase-google-signin-error-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10)
11. [Google sign in failed com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619229/google-sign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10)
12. [Why do I get com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437678/why-do-i-get-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10)
13. [Error with Google_sign_in plugin in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56381137/error-with-google-sign-in-plugin-in-flutter)

And I've tried all of the solutions:

- [Generated debug key](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)
- Entered SHA1 debug key on the [Firebase site](https://console.firebase.google.com)
- Verified that my email was entered on the Firebase site.
- Downloaded the google-services.json file and put it in the `android/app/` directory
- Built the flutter app using `flutter build appbundle --debug`
- PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)

So I also tried:

- With just the release key on the Firebase site and built with `flutter build appbundle --release`
- With both the release key and the debug key
- With the SHA256 for each combination above
- With each of these combinations, I was sure to `flutter clean` and replace the google-services.json file with the updated one
- Verified that `android/build.gradle` and `android/app/build.gradle` were [configured properly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup)
- Verified that "Google" was enabled as a "Sign-in Method" was enabled on the Firebase site
- I even filled out the [OAuth consent screen](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent) with my app name, logo, email, homepage, privacy, & terms of service links and saved

Here are the versions that I'm running with:

```
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.7
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
```

Relevant portion of the android/app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Relevant portion of the android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}
```

Flutter doctor output:

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0-rc1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.38.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

All testing was done on multiple devices using the Robo test lab on Firebase (only to see if the login was successful, not to test the UI).

---

TLDR;
In the end, I finally figured out that it works if I build the apk using `flutter build apk` (as opposed to an appbundle).  Then I realized that the problem started about the same time that flutter started recommending that I generate appbundles instead of apks.

**Has anyone been able to sign in a BRAND NEW USER with flutter using google_sign_in when generating an appbundle?**  (Keep in mind that existing users who previously signed in to an earlier version of the app work without issue.)

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same issue on Mac but the app works on windows. Whats OS are you using? and java version? I see that we have identically app configuration... If I fix it, I'll let you know! Let me know please if you fix it please

Comment: @MauroSebastianVolpeParedes I've tried building on both Linux Mint and Windows 10.  Both have the same behavior (apk works, abb errors).  jdk1.8.0_152 on Windows.

Comment: Did you enroll in Play Signing from the start or did you have an existing app that you enrolled later?

Comment: @Pierre, It's been a while, but I think this was an existing app in the Play Store that I enrolled in Play Signing after some time.  How is that relevant?

Comment: Trying to see if this could be related to signature authentication, but probably not. Is there any common pattern among the devices that can't log in?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior, exception only occurs when the App bundle is used but not with an APK. Did you ever find the root cause?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **Internal App Sharing** to test Flutter builds on actual Android devices (like I am), there is **another App Signing certificate fingerprint** you need to add.

On the left navigation of Google Play Console go to: **Developer Tools -> Internal App Sharing**

Select the **App Certificate** tab. Should look something like this:

[Google Play - Internal App Sharing - Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy52q.png)

**Copy the SHA1 key and add it to the Firebase Console** -> Project Settings -> [your Android app] -> SHA certificate fingerprints (use the button to Add fingerprint)

Download your **updated google-services.json** and update/add it in your android/app folder of your project.

This works with new users and existing users. I built the an appbundle (not APK) using `flutter build appbundle`

This isn't documented anywhere by Google and I have not seen this solution elsewhere in the Flutter community. I came across this solution while poking around in the Google Play console after trying all of your referenced links and several others.